# Want to check RANSAC for a noiseless set of points; Error: Not enough inliers

Tags: point-cloud, ransac

I was just checking the functioning of my code implementing RANSAC sac_model: perpendicular by checking for a noiseless pointcloud. I have a few questions in the steps:
I did the following:
To generate noiseless point cloud:

1. I collected 3 points from my current point cloud being published , used an online plane equation calculator[image]
2. The plane equation found here and the plane coefficents I find from RANSAC are same. So it is verified that my usage(implementation of RANSAC is correct I am assuming.)
   But I need to verify by checking if all points lie on the plane in rviz
3. I generate 500 points using the
   i) one of the points from pointcloud (also used in above equation to find eqn of plane)
   ii) plane coefficients as normal vector
   Almost all The 500 points have their z values close to -3;
   That 500 points were generated in MATLAB coz I am more familiar in MATLAB coding.
   I also visualize these points in MATLAB
   I do not understand why enough inliers are not found considering all of them are generated from plane equation.
   [image]
4. Now I copy my 500 points in a pcd file and read it in my code to perform RANSAC  on the points. The RANSAC yields following error:[image]

Comment: Could you share your code? The part where you implement ransac. I am interested in your parameters.

Comment: Also, can you verify your pointcloud (pcd) is correct? You can use `pcl_viewer <name>.pcd` on a linux terminal

Comment: How are you outputting the points from Matlab to pcd? How are you generating the plane in Matlab?